# Compiling documentation of a package

Tags: packages, documentation, debugging, dtx

I have extracted the documentation of the `longtable` package and I want to compile it alone. By extracting the documentation I mean that I have copied the `.dtx` file from the `\maketitle` to the end and I've pasted it in a `tex` file, so I have something like:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\title{The \textsf{longtable}...
...
\end{document}
```

I have a `minimal scheme tlmgr installation` with the packages:

```
latex latex-bin koma-script tools amsmath babel carlisle ec geometry graphics hyperref lm marvosym oberdiek parskip pdftex-def url hyphen-spanish
```

Right know I'm getting the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence \fileversion
```

I want to know what to do to compile it without errors. The reason is I want to give just the source of the translated documentation attached to it.

Comment: why? But anyway you must be doing something wrong and you haven't provided a usable log. longtable uses the doc package for documentation and that defines \fileversion

Comment: what do you mean by "extracted" longtable.dtx is distributed in that form, there is nothing to extract, just process it with pdflatex. (or in any modern tex distribution just use `texdoc longtable` and the documentation will be displayed)

Comment: Why aren't installing packages the sane way using `tlmgr`?

Comment: Also, you have already installed `longtable`. It is included in the list of packages you posted in the question. (It is part of `tools`.) Unless you have set things up very non-standardly, you therefore already have a compiled copy of the documentation.

Comment: I'll read the tlmgr documentation because right know I dont know what is the sane way.

Comment: You asked quite some odd questions lately, wann come to chat and tell us a bit about it? I am just curious. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: In your edited question you have shown a file that isn't the longtable documentation. Just do `pdflatex longtable.dtx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ltxdoc` is designed to be used as an extension of `doc` with source files in `doc` format written as comments on the source file. If used in that way, `doc` arranges for `\fileversion` to be defined based on the `\ProvidesPackage` argument in the documented sources.

In comments it is clear that the intention is to produce translated documentation. For that I think it is better to make a normal (say `article` class) document that translates/paraphrases the documentation as necessary and doesn't aim to look like a documented *source* and in particular is distributed without copying the original package.

While TeX systems can cope with multiple files of the same name, and by managing TEXINPUTS you can arrange for the correct version to be included in each context, it is a complication that most users never have to deal with and so it would be unfortunate if teh distribution of an introductory guide caused that complication.